# I get `TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)` error when I use multi inherit

Tags: python, python-2.7, oop, inheritance, super

I'm new to python, I have a test.py file with code bellow:

```py
class Person(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        super(Person, self).__init__()
        self.name = name

class Skill(object):
    def __init__(self, skillName):
        super(Skill, self).__init__()
        self.skillName = skillName

class Student(Person, Skill):
    def __init__(self, name, score):
        super(Student, self).__init__(name)
        self.score = score

s = Student('Paul', 90)
```

And when I try to run this python file, I got an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 16, in <module>
    s = Student('Paul', 90)
  File "test.py", line 13, in __init__
    super(Student, self).__init__(name)
  File "test.py", line 3, in __init__
    super(Person, self).__init__()
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

And when I remove `super(Person, self).__init__()` in class Person's `__init__`, no error occurs, Can anybody tell me why?

My python version is: 2.7.10

Comment: The `__init__` methods calling `super(...).__init__()` might be calling *anything*, and they form a chain. You need to pass along all the pieces of information that each `__init__` method needs. See the duplicate, specifically Aran-Fey's answer there. You normally give each `__init__` method a `**kwargs` catch-all part that you then use to pass on extra pieces of information to the next `__init__` method, and use `super(...).__init__(name=name, skillName=skillName)` from the `Student.__init__()` method because it received those by name.

Comment: See https://gist.github.com/mjpieters/0bbd0264ba71bf2b9041b5cd2622cf08 for a working version of that.